# what i need to set the release for app store submission

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval

I am so much confusing with these settings for app store.Can any one please clarify it. Those are Edit scheme settings and What certificates i need to set for Debug, Distribution and Release at the time of submitting app to app store.[image: Please tell me are these settings ok for app submission]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps :

**1) Click on plus and and duplicate release configuration[image]**

**2) Edit scheme so that archive is done using distribution** [image]

**3) Click you distribution profile as code signing identity** [image]

**4) Then next to Run .in Xcode..make sure you have your device selected..not the simulator..then Go to Product and click archive..The Rest step will be easy since Xcode will help you in the,.**

Comment: Thanks for your response. In code signing wat about release .we need to keep either developer or distribution certificate.

Comment: if you have duplicated release config.(1st step) and then change archive to distribute(2nd step) ..then choose the distribution certificate in distribution config only..no need for release